# Can I extract the automatic title generated by the xarray plot contourf call?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, python-xarray

I am working with an xarray `DataSet` with 8 dimensions. To do mapping, I apply 6 `sel()` or `isel()` to the `DataSet` leaving only the `latitude` and `longitude` dimensions. I can then plot this onto a map using the xarray `plot.contourf()` hooks. A title for the plot is automatically generated containing the information of which slice was `select`ed. The title looks like `Dim1=Val1,Dim2=Val2,Dim3=Val3...` The title is too long to fit over the plot.

How do I either:

1. extract this title so that I can manipulate it as an annotation?
2. tell xarray to use word wrap and put a multi-line title?

UPDATE: I can get the title using `title=ax.get_title()`. However, the xarray routine that auto-generates the title also auto-truncates it, so the title looks like this:

```
%print(title)
'case = Case1, range = 20.0, band = Band1, senso...'
```

That truncation is probably done somewhere too deep in the code to retrieve, but I'm open to clever solutions!

Comment: Best is to create the axes and then call data.contour(ax=ax)

Comment: I'm multiplexing the plot, so I am actually doing it that way. Does that help with getting access to the automatically generated plot title?

Comment: Then you can just do ax.set_title.

Comment: That gave me a clue-- I made edits to question above.

Comment: Your xarray likely has all the info you need to make your own title. Or if you want to see how they are doing it: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/blob/b9739f7c3a8644998e5b7a412b67ebaa81b81182/xarray/core/dataarray.py#L3057